# Clarification about partial derivative

Tags: derivatives

I have $H(q,p,t)$. I also know that $q$ and $p$ depend on $\alpha$.

Why $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial \alpha}$=$ \frac {\partial H}{\partial q} \frac {\partial q}{\partial \alpha}+ \frac {\partial  H}{\partial p} \frac {\partial p}{\partial \alpha}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In problems like this there's a tendency to use the same name for different functions, which I think causes confusion.  Let's state very carefully that $H:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, and that $p$ and $q$ are *functions* from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Let $\hat{H}(\alpha,t) = H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)$.  Note that $\hat{H}$ is a different function than $H$ !  We wish to compute
$\frac{\partial \hat{H}(\alpha,t)}{\partial \alpha}$.

We can use the chain rule to write down the answer directly.  But here is a computation that shows some intuition behind the chain rule.  We will use the approximations
\begin{equation}
H(P + \Delta P,Q + \Delta Q,t) \approx H(P,Q,t) +
\frac{\partial H(P,Q,t)}{\partial P} \Delta P +
\frac{\partial H(P,Q,t)}{\partial Q} \Delta Q
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
p(\alpha + \Delta \alpha) \approx p(\alpha) + p'(\alpha) \Delta \alpha.
\end{equation}

Here is how we can derive the chain rule in this situation:

\begin{align*}
\hat{H}(\alpha + \Delta \alpha,t) &= H(p(\alpha + \Delta \alpha),q(\alpha + \Delta \alpha),t) \\
&\approx H(p(\alpha) + p'(\alpha) \Delta \alpha,q(\alpha) + q'(\alpha) \Delta \alpha,t)\\
&\approx H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t) + 
\frac{\partial H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)}{\partial P} p'(\alpha) \Delta \alpha
+ \frac{\partial H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)}{\partial Q} q'(\alpha) \Delta \alpha \\
&= \hat{H}(\alpha,t) + 
\left( \frac{\partial H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)}{\partial P} p'(\alpha) + 
\frac{\partial H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)}{\partial Q} q'(\alpha) \right) \Delta \alpha.
\end{align*}

Comparing this with the equation
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}(\alpha + \Delta \alpha,t) \approx \hat{H}(\alpha,t) + 
\frac{\partial \hat{H}(\alpha,t)}{\partial \alpha} \Delta \alpha
\end{equation}
we see that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{H}(\alpha,t)}{\partial \alpha}
= 
\frac{\partial H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)}{\partial P} p'(\alpha) + 
\frac{\partial H(p(\alpha),q(\alpha),t)}{\partial Q} q'(\alpha) .
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

If you think of $H(q,p)$ as a function on a two dimensional plane with coordinates $(q,p)$, then 
$$\vec \pi(\alpha)=(q(\alpha),p(\alpha))$$ 
is a curve, it's tangent vector a 2x2 vector 
$$\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\vec \pi(\alpha)=(q'(\alpha),p'(\alpha)).$$ 
Your expression is the scalar product with the [gradient](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20568/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-a-gradient/20571#20571) of 
$$\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}H=\vec \nabla H\cdot\tfrac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\vec \pi(\alpha)$$ 
imposed by the chain rule.